# Private images created by aws marketplace

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

[image]

I'm not sure how these CentOS/EMR AMIs appeared under `Private images`. How can I remove them?

Comment: Do you have EC2 instances created from these AMIs currently running?

Comment: Did you create the images?

Comment: I have no EC2 instances running. The owner of these AMI != self.

Comment: If you are not the owner, you cannot remove it.

Comment: But why did it appear under my account as private images? How can I remove these since they don't belong to me.

Answer (score 0):

The AMI is not public, it is private but shared with few other AWS accounts. Your account happens to be one of the shared accounts.

What it means is the AMI owner is allowing you to launch his AMI but it doesn't mean you can delete (deregister) his AMI.

See [AMI Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ComponentsAMIs.html)